# SKOverlay in Appclip shows up but won't open the App store - UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, overlay

I am able to get the overlay to pop up in my appclip that asks the user to download the full app. However, nothing happens when I click on it.

```
  func displayOverlay() {
           guard let scene = self.window?.windowScene else { return }
           let config = SKOverlay.AppClipConfiguration(position: .bottom)
           let overlay = SKOverlay(configuration: config)
           overlay.delegate = self
           overlay.present(in: scene)
       }
```

I added this code in my scene delegate file and call it from another function. It's being called fine.

Comment: I'm using this snippet in SwiftUI:
.appStoreOverlay(isPresented: $showAppStoreOverlay) {
            SKOverlay.AppClipConfiguration(position: .bottom)
        },
but I still have the 'Get the full app' grayed out in the banner and Can't download the app. Did you find a solution?